# Random forest cross-validaton by patient

Tags: r, cross-validation, random-forest, train-test-split

I have a dataset of various features from 10 patients and 10 controls. Each patient has many data points.
Random forest does an amazing job in predicting whether a data point is from a patient or a control when using a random 70%-30% train-test split or a 10 K fold cross validation.

Then I realised this is because part of the training data and test data overlap. That is, some data points in the training set are from Patient A, and surely when using this model to predict Patient A's own data, it is very accurate.

I tried to split the data by patients and use 'LOOCV', leaving one patient out as a test set each time. However, when I do that, the random forest models can't run because in the test set there's only one category (i.e. 'patient', and there's no 'control').

I use R

```
rftrain <- randomForest(group ~ person_id + many other features, 
                    data = train, localImp = TRUE)

# Pyellowictive Model Evaluation with test data
confusion <- confusionMatrix(predict(rftrain, test), test$group, positive = "patient")
confusion
```

Is there a better package or better way for this evaluation?
Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much for flagging up the inclusion of 'patient_id' that's such a good point that I missed! And thanks for the resources about leaving-one-subject-out. I'll search further for the r implementation. If you have any recommendations, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: @civilstat: Could you make that into a formal answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question "Is there a better package or better way for this evaluation?" but...

You probably shouldn't be using `person_id` as an explanatory variable. Even if you fit a model that you're happy with for the 20 people in your study, you wouldn't be able to use it to make predictions for any new people.

I suspect that removing `patient_id` is not just conceptually a good idea, but it should also fix R's complaints. If it doesn't, and your question really is about debugging software, you may get better answers at [StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), because here on CrossValidated we tend to focus more on concepts than on software implementations.

All that being said, your plan for CV (leaving one whole patient out at a time) is a good idea. See for example the "subject-wise CV" of [Saeb et al. (2017), "The need to approximate the use-case in clinical machine learning."](https://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5441397/)